# Como exibir uma matriz graficamente?

Tags: java, matriz

Tenho uma matriz `Tabuleiro[][] tabuleiro = New Tabuleiro[20][20]`.

Ela contém objetos de uma classe ainda não implementada, que terá alguns valores, como por exemplo a cor da célula e um marcador de posição.

Gostaria de saber se é possível exibir graficamente essa matriz, por exemplo, os campos do tabuleiro, da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, que representar graficamente essa matriz, de forma bem básica mesmo.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO em Português! Visite a Central de Ajuda (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender melhor como realizar as perguntas! Do modo como colocou, sua pergunta esta muito ampla, e um simples "Sim, é possível." a responderia mas obviamente te deixaria insatisfeito. Seja mais específico com relação ao seu problema e nos mostre o que tentou para podermos auxiliar melhor.

Comment: A questão é que não sei nada de interface gráfica. E queria saber um método fácil para representar essa tabela de forma gráfica.

Comment: Então, Eduardo, como o colega já comentou a sua questão está muito ampla. Há diversas formas de desenhar algo parecido. Uma imagem, aliás, não deixa de ser uma matriz bidimensional de pixels. Sugiro que você edite a pergunta pra *ao menos* fornecer mais informações sobre o que deve ser "desenhado" em cada posição da sua matriz (onde está o código da classe "Tabuleiro"?). Além disso, se você "não sabe nada" de interface gráfica, não vai ser com uma questão que suas dúvidas serão todas resolvidas. Que tal começar com algo mais simples, e ir postando suas dúvidas aqui aos poucos? :)

Comment: Você pode, por exemplo, tentar desenhar uma unidade dessa classe: http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/basicdrawing/

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue criar um *panel* e definir o tamanho dele, por exemplo 50x50.

Aí, você faz um *loop* dentro de outro *loop*, para conseguir fazer as linhas e colunas da matriz e cria para cada posição um *panel* novo.

```
for(int i = 0; i<n_linhas;i++){
   for(int j=0; i<n_colunas;j++){
       //cria um novo panel, define borda,tamanho,posição inicial
}
```

A posição inicial do *panel*, você leva em consideração o tamanho que você definiu, e o tamanho de cada *panel*. Aí você define a posição inicial como sendo `width: i*height,j*width`.